# Magit - How can I checkout a remote branch locally without typing the entire branch name?

Tags: magit

I have a remote branch `remote-branch-long-name`. When I magit checkout with helm completion I can type `remote-branch` and `origin/remote-branch-long-name` will show up as an option. The issue is that to checkout this branch locally, I actually cannot switch to that branch, I need to switch to `remote-branch-long-name (without the origin/ prefix)`, since helm doesn't provide that as a completion option, I have to manually type the entire branch name out.

Is there another function I should be using for this use case or do I have to hack a function together?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It sounds like the problem you are trying to solve is not the problem you are encountering.  Git doesn't allow you to work locally with remote branches (the `origin/remote-branch-long-name` you see is just a tracking branch; you can't work with it directly) and Magit is guiding you toward the intended workflow.

Since you want to work with `origin/remote-branch-long-name` you should probably run `magit-branch-and-checkout` (`b` `c`).  Select `origin/remote-branch-long-name` and it will prompt you for a local branch name and will default to `remote-branch-long-name`.  This gives you the local branch need to make your changes.  When are done with your changes and push to `origin/remote-branch-long-name` it will update the remote tracking branch.

You can have local branches with a slash in them, but using a remote name in a local branch name can make things very confusing.  Git remembers which remote a local branch was checked out from, so you don't need to track it yourself.

For a more complete explanation than my answer here (!) you find this [page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) a to be good overview about remotes.

Comment: I think the disconnect here is that the Magit flow is different from the git flow. If you run `git checkout foo`, and `foo` is not a branch, but `origin/foo` is, git will create a new branch `foo` and set it to track `origin/foo`. So git teaches you to think "I just checkout `foo`, and git does everything necessary". But this does not work with magit; running `magit-branch-and-checkout` is the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

Since magit v2.12.0, there's a command `magit-branch-checkout`, bound to `b l` (Checkout local branch), that does exactly what you want.  See [the doc](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Branch-Commands)  for details.

Comment: I did `F p` but I don't see `origin/name-of-my-branch` when I do `b c`. After running the command `git pull origin` I'm able to `b l` to it. Why does pulling through magit not work the same way as pulling through git?

Comment: Assuming that `origin` *is* your push remote... You've used two different commands.  `b c` and `b l` read the branch argument differently.

Comment: what I'm saying is that I have the branch pushed up on github but I don't have it locally. neither command lets me use it's name until I pull using the git command. How do I pull it through magit?

Comment: `F p` only fetches the branch you're pulling from (you'll see from the process log that Magit passes the `<refspec>` argument).  Use `f p` to do a general `git fetch`, and then `b l` will know what `origin/name-of-my-branch` is.

Comment: `git pull` on the command line also fetching other branches by default is a slightly weird quirk, so using that command purely for that side-effect is an equally quirky workflow.  If fetching *other* branches is the goal, then `git fetch` is the appropriate command.